# How to know fragment is attached to which activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I'm having two activity and one fragment.I attach fragment to both activity. Now my problem is I have to which is the current activity to fragment is attached. Note my first activity will be destroyed when i was in second activity.

Comment: use by checking `instanceof`

Comment: *I attach fragment to both activity* seriously? it is not possible at all

Comment: i think what he meant be like , he attaches the fragment on Activities at different point of time @Selvin

Comment: Why is this not possible? By using frame layout we can achieve this.

Comment: May i know the reason for negative opinion?

Comment: @user6444945 have you tried `getActivity()` inside fragment,??

Comment: you really can't attach one fragment instance to 2 activities at the same time. Only if you have 2 different instances of fragment

Comment: I already said my first activity will be destroyed when I was in second activity.That means fragment will no longer will be attached in first activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this snippet

```
getActivity().getClass().getName();
```